# Unix time in obj-C vs python

Tags: python, objective-c

I am comparing my functions to get a timestamp in Obj-C and in python. Here are the two functions:

```
// Obj-C
NSTimeInterval secondsSinceUnixEpoch = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
double nonceLng = (double)(secondsSinceUnixEpoch) * 1000000;
NSString *nonce = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.0f", nonceLng];
NSLog(nonce);
==> 1422379701020979

// Python
>>> int(time.time()*1e6)
==> 1422379701239615
```

Is there a way to make the Obj-C part more compact? Or, is the above really the way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Python code is all on one line yet you split the Objective-C code into three lines. The Python code appears to be returning the value as some sort of integer yet your Objective-C code converts the number to a string.

And the Python console automatically logs the result while you need an explicit `NSLog` to see the Objective-C value.

So try this:

```
long long timestamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000000;
NSLog(@"%lld", timestamp);
```

Not counting the `NSLog`, it's now more comparable.

Comment: what's the difference between `long long` and `double` ?

Comment: `long long` is an integer type. `double` is a floating point type.